# java.io.FileNotFoundException for a file sent in Spark-submit --files

Tags: apache-spark

In my spark application, I have a properties file which I need to initialise things like database connections and other business logic etc. When I submitted the spark job in cluster mode, I see this file uploaded but when I check if file exists, I get a `false` and file not found during initialisation:

```
spark2-submit \
--class "com.packageName.MyApp" \
--files MyProject/config/configFile.properties  \
--master yarn --num-executors 2 \
--executor-cores 2 --deploy-mode cluster \
myapp-assembly-0.1.jar configFile.properties
```

And I see in the logs:

```
19/01/11 10:21:15 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/home/dexter/MyProject/lib/myapp-assembly-0.1.jar -> hdfs://XXXXXXX.com:8020/user/dexter/.sparkStaging/application_1541792367360_580444/myapp-assembly-0.1.jar
19/01/11 10:21:19 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/home/dexter/MyProject/config/configFile.properties -> hdfs://XXXXXXX.com:8020/user/dexter/.sparkStaging/application_1541792367360_580444/configFile.properties
```

And in the code to initialise file:

```
val configFileSpark = SparkFiles.get(args(0))
println(configFileSpark)  
// /vol10/yarn/nm/usercache/dexter/appcache/application_1541792367360_580444/spark-3dec2688-a749-44eb-a7d6-ecded2ec5111/userFiles-c6ed268c-e847-4ffd-a5cf-f7956357ac4f/configFile.properties

val configFile = new File(configFileSpark)
println("File exists: " + configFile.exists())    
// false

val props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream(configFile.getAbsolutePath()));
// java.io.FileNotFoundException: /vol10/yarn/nm/usercache/dexter/appcache/application_1541792367360_580444/spark-3dec2688-a749-44eb-a7d6-ecded2ec5111/userFiles-c6ed268c-e847-4ffd-a5cf-f7956357ac4f/configFile.properties (No such file or directory)
```

I'm really confused about how to go about getting this file and using it for initialisation. Any solution besides uploading properties file on HDFS?

Comment: Could you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The `--files` param doesn't work with `--deploy-mode "client"` (which is the default mode) but it works with `--deploy-mode "cluster"`.

Comment: even in yarn mode I get file not found exception